# Movie about a man with a "programmable" brain

Tags: story-identification, movie, spy

During the early 80's I remember watching a movie (I don't believe it was a series) about a man whose brain could be programmed with various skills (actually a lot like *The Matrix*).

If memory serves whenever he would access these programmed skills it would show a brief cutaway to the old magnetic tape drives on those old computers. I also remember that it took sometime for these skills to be "remembered." A few of the skills learned were racecar driving, playing the piano, etc. I don't remember him keeping these skills indefinitely nor having more than one new skill at a time. I also believe the government used him as a kind of spy.

Comment: Could it be "Brainstorm" (1983) or "The Man with One Red Shoe" (1985), or in "Quantum Leap" Sam Beckett  learned new skills when he jumped into people's bodies.  Could you have combined more than one movie/series in your memory?

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been mentioned yet, but are you possibly thinking of Johnny Mnemonic (Keanu Reeves movie) or The Pretender (the series)?

Comment: (P.S. If you watch the opening credits of Johnny Mnemonic, you might be a little freaked out at how accurately it described 2020/2021...)

Comment: It makes me think of Joe 90!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Ultimate Imposter** (1979 TV movie)?

This was, according to the 1 user review on IMDb.com. a failed "backdoor pilot" based on an episode of "The Six Million Dollar Man" TV series. It was episode 12 of season 4 and it had the same title. This movie debuted near the time that you indicated, but I wonder if you're remembering the series episode. The full movie is on YouTube, but I will post the trailer below. It includes scenes of the mc in a racing car and shows the old magnetic tape drives and old computers. In the movie, the mc could only retain the programmed information and skills for 72 hours.

Comment: Yup this is it. The moment i saw this scene I knew it was the right one. Good job.

Comment: Oh my. Erin Grey.

Answer (score 19):

Could this be [*Joe 90*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_90)?

> It follows the exploits of nine-year-old schoolboy Joe McClaine, who
> becomes a spy after his adoptive father invents a device capable of
> recording expert knowledge and experience and transferring it to
> another human brain. Armed with the skills of the world's top academic
> and military minds, Joe is recruited by the World Intelligence Network
> (WIN) as its "Most Special Agent".

The device used to download the skills was a big whirry tape thingie.

> [image]

The episode *[International Concerto](https://gerryanderson.fandom.com/wiki/International_Concerto)* has him taking on the skills of a concert pianist and the episode [*The Race*](https://gerryanderson.fandom.com/wiki/The_Race) has him given the brain pattern of a Monte Carlo Rally driver.

Note that this was a TV show not a movie, but the pilot and the second episode were often shown together as an hour-long special.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to add something at the bottom of the answer after the dashes?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not this. What i saw was definitely live action and the main character was an adult male.  However this has so much of the stuff i remember i wonder if the movie was based on this.

Comment: @MrInfinity - There was no Joe 90 film

Comment: @Clockwork - No. I was going to put the episodes below the line, then changed my mind.

Comment: My bad I should have been clearer. The movie I was referring to was the one I was looking for.  The Joe 90 show bares many of the same things I saw in the movie im looking for. Alas though its not Joe 90.

Comment: I'd never really appreciated before just how many bits of recognisable tape handling technology they'd put in that model. I remembered the zig-zag path (commonly used on big paper tape readers), but there's also a videotape spinning-drum and something very much like the innards of a QIC-style cartridge.